# Strange behaviour of c++ constructor

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm testing this code and wondering why this wasn't failed at compile time ?. I'm using c++11 and g++ 4.7.2.

I had similar structure on my production code, it was giving errors at run time, then I found that I'm constructing the class with wrong argument type.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>


typedef std::vector<std::string> Word;

class Data {
    public:
        const Word &word;
        Data(Word w) : word(w) {}
};

class Base{
    const Data &data;
    public:
        Base(const Data &d): data(d) {}
        ~Base() {}
};

class Work : public Base{
    public:
        Work(const Data &d): Base(d){}
        ~Work() {}
};


int main(int argc, char **argv){
    Word words;
    words.push_back("work");

    /*
    * I'm confused with this constructor, why this passed the compilation
    * ??
    * Any special rule to reason this scenario ??
    *
    * But obviously it will fail at run time.
    */
    const Work *work  = new Work(words);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Maybe an implicit conversion is going on somewhere?

Comment: The words are convert to Data by the Data constructor and then call the Work(Data)

Comment: Why it should fail? On http://ideone.com/cxkf4X it returns Success.

Comment: Beside the question, Isn't it an undefined behavior due to dangling reference in `Data` class? The `word` refers to a temporary object.

Comment: It is. I recommend Data { const Word& word; Data(Word&); }; and so on ... Maybe even Data { Word& word; Data(Word&); }; to get a decent compiler error if the argument in the constructor does not match.

Comment: @MM. Like this, it is not UB. As soon as it is used, the UB is invoked.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`Data` is constructible from `Word`, so you can pass a `Word` to the `Work` constructor. Under the hood, an instance of `Data` will be created from the passed `Word` and, in turn, passed to the constructor.

You can avoid this by marking the constructor of `Data` that takes a `Word` as [explicit](https://stackoverflow.com/q/121162/464709), like this:

```
class Data {
    public:
        const Word &word;
        explicit Data(Word w) : word(w) {}
};
```

That way, the constructor cannot be implicitly applied anymore, and your call to the `Work` constructor will fail to compile unless you explicitly invoke the `Data` constructor:

```
const Work *work  = new Work(words);        // Implicit call, fails to compile.
const Work *work  = new Work(Data(words));  // Explicit call, compiles.
```

Comment: Of course, the constructor of `Data` won't work, because it binds the reference to the argument, which will be destructed when the constructor returns.

Comment: @MM., yes, it is. `words` being local to `main()` does not matter much because the instance of `Work` is also local to `main()`, but the `Work` constructor holds to a temporary `Data` instance, as James points out, and that's bad news indeed.

Comment: Now I understood why my program gives segfault while run time ( crashes when accessing the dangling reference).

Answer (score 5):

It <strike>works</strike> compiles<sup>*</sup> because `Data` has an implicit conversion constructor that takes a `Word` reference:

```
Data(Word w) : word(w) {}
```

This means you can do things such as

```
Word words;
Data d1 = words;
Data d2(words);
```

and you can construct a `Work` from a `Data` via constructor `Work(const Data &d): Base(d){}`:

```
Work w(d2);
```

which means the following is also valid, because it only involves one user-defined conversion:

```
Work w2(words); // constructs Data temporary from words, then constructs w2 with it
```

This behaviour can be suppressed by declaring the converting constructor as `explicit`:

```
explicit Data(Word w) : word(w) {}
```

<sup>* Your doesn't actually work because it involves a dangling reference to a temporary `Data` object</sup>

Comment: Beside the question, Isn't it an undefined behavior due to dangling reference in `Data` class? The `word` refers to a temporary object.

Comment: @MM. I was just adding a note about that :)

Answer (score 2):

After exit of the following constructor, the data member `word` of reference type will be referencing an object that no longer exists:

```
class Data {
    public:
        const Word &word;
        Data(Word w) : word(w) {}
};
```

A variable of automatic storage duration is created to hold `w`.  You store a reference to that variable as a member `word`, then the referee is destroyed on exit of the constructor.

Regardless of the other problems, I don't think this is your intention.